# UIAutomator is unable to fetch objects in dump.xml for specific apps

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-uiautomator

I am using the `UIAutomator` Viewer tool of AndroidSDK. It works well but with some Apps, there are UIElements which are not recognized in the UI dump.xml, and therefore, the `UIAutomator` Viewer is not able to fetch those objects in the Tree Hierarchy.

This problem persists on all Android versions. Need to know whether this is a bug of `UIAutomator` and is there some workaround for it.

*See the Image:*

1. The Tree should show more hierarchy(Cesky, Deutsch ect)
2. The class of this element is shown to be android.view.view(which is the base class)

[image: The Tree should show more hierarchy]

Comment: Similar question found with no useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782517/android-uiautomatorviewer-cant-detect-some-views

Comment: I think it is related to "Ensuring your Activity is accessible"
http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

`However, some apps use custom view elements to provide a richer user experience. Such custom elements won't get the accessibility support that is provided by the standard Android UI elements. If this applies to your app, make sure that it exposes the custom-drawn UI element to Android accessibility services by implementing the AccessibilityNodeProvider class.`